# Debian, wifi card driver problem

Tags: debian, wifi, drivers, intel

**Nice day to all!**
I have installed Debian on my new laptop, but wifi card is not working!
I have installed the firmware-iwlwifi package, and module gets loaded through /etc/modules file;
**Any help is greatly appreciated :) !**
p.s. I have searched and tried other solutions, but nothing works.

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:640-63f memory:6403134000-6403137fff


lspci
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 51e0 (rev 01)

lsmod | grep -i iwl
iwlwifi               299008  0
cfg80211              983040  1 iwlwifi
```

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -knn |grep -i net -A3`, it is more detailed.

Answer (score 0):

The AX211 require a kernel version 5.14 and later. See [Linux wireless](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi).

You can install the `linux-image-amd64 (5.18.16-1~bpo11+1)` from [backports](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/)